# How to hide an HTML input field with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to hide a text input field with javascript. Changing its type attribute to hidden does not work in IE (security issue).

What would be the best way to do it?

Note: No jQuery or other lib can be assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have to show and hide the text field dynamically based on changing conditions in the form, otherwise you'd just make it an `<input type="hidden"...` to begin with.

Keep your code that shows and hides the field as it is, but also catch the `onsubmit` event.

In the submit handler, get your text field via `document.getElementById(...)` (or by accessing `document.forms[i]`) and check to see whether or not it's hidden.

If it *is* hidden, create a new DOM node for an `<input type="hidden" ...>` field and add that node to the form, probably via `myform.appendChild(...)`. You'll have to give it the name your server-side code expects. Copy the contents of the hidden text field into the newly created type=hidden field, then return from your submit handler, allowing the standard submit to continue.

You could also just un-hide the text field on submit, but you'd have to move it "off screen" also or the user would see it reappear during submit processing.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can change it is before you append it to the DOM. You can make a new element and then replace the current one with it.

Look at replaceChild and createElement since you want to do manual DOM scripting. I assume you know what to do.

EDIT: "Hidden" fields as far as I know **are** sent. Have you checked whether they are? And you can also just do `position:absolute; left:-9999em;` to offset them.

Comment: Re `position:absolute` - yes, but then it remains in the tab order. If you also disable it that will prevent tabbing, but will it still get sent on submit?

Answer (score 0):

document.myform.myelement.style.display = 'none'

works as expected even in Internet Explorer.

Comment: then the value is not submitted as part of form submission

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a div or span and then setting the display style to none when you want to hide it, and then to block (if you used a div) or inline (if you used a span) when you want to show it.

Comment: I need the value to be sent in form submission. As far as I know hidden items are not being sent by all browsers (except for input type='hidden')